# C++ thread pool and pass future as parameters

Tags: c++, multithreading

Hello I am working on thread pool implementation, my idea is to
use two thread pools, for example, input data is passed to first thread pool
and return as future, which is then passed to second thread pool

I am trying to use thread pool code from
github.com/Tyler-Hardin/thread_pool

the core part of code is as following

```
template<typename Ret> 
std::future<Ret> async(std::function<Ret()> f){ 
typedef std::function<Ret()> F; 

std::promise<Ret> *p = new std::promise<Ret>; 

// Create a function to package as a task. 
auto task_wrapper = [p](F&& f){ 
    p->set_value(std::move(f())); 
}; 

// Create a function to package as a future for the user to wait on. 
auto ret_wrapper = [p]() -> Ret{ 
    auto temp = std::move(p->get_future().get()); 

// Clean up resources 
    delete p; 
    return std::move(temp); 
}; 

task_mutex.lock(); 

// Package the task wrapper into a function to execute as a task. 
auto task = std::async(std::launch::deferred,  
    task_wrapper, 
    std::move(f)); 

// Push the task onto the work queue. 
tasks.emplace_back(std::move(task)); 

task_mutex.unlock(); 

// complete and to get the result. 
return std::async(std::launch::deferred,  
ret_wrapper); 
}
```

Now what I am trying to do is as following
first I have two processing functions.

```
int func1(int i1)
{
    // do something
    return i1; 
}

int func2(std::future<int> &i2)
{
   int i3 = i2.get();
   // do something
   return i3;
}
```

The calling codes is as following

```
int input = 1;
1
std::future<int> ret1 = tpool1->async(std::function<int(int)>func1, input);

2
std::future<int> ret2 = tpool2->async(std::function<int(std::future<int> &)>func2, std::ref(ret1));
```

The problem is 1) can compile successfully, 2) meet compilation error 
 "no matching parameters"

I tried different things and none works, can anyone help me here?

Comment: Why are you taking a future by reference?

Comment: actually here is what confusing me  if use std::move(ret1) I got error of  "attempting to reference a deleted function"